# Why do pd.DataFrame pickle sizes vary so much between df.to_pickle and native Python pickle?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I have a pandas dataframe (pd.DataFrame) with the following structure:

```
In [175]: df.dtypes.value_counts()
Out[175]: 
int64      876
float64    206
object      76
bool         9
dtype: int64

In [176]: df.shape
Out[176]: (9764, 1167)
```

I've stored the data to disk in the following three ways:

```
In [170]: df.to_csv('df.csv')

In [171]: df.to_pickle('df_v1.pkl')

In [172]: import pickle
In [173]: with open('df_v2.pkl', 'wb') as handle:
   .....:     pickle.dump(df, handle)
```

The sizes of the files on disk are as follows:

```
df.csv:     26.4 MB 
df_v1.pkl:  90.5 MB
df_v2.pkl: 340.4 MB
```

The `csv` is understandably small - it has no pandas overhead to save (that is, it doesn't have to save dataframe dtypes, etc.)
What I don't understand is why the `pickle`s from the two different `pickle`-ing methods differ so much in size! Also, is one preferred over the other? And what about backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/pickle.py#L4) for `to_pickle`, pandas chooses the most efficient protocol possible when it pickles the DataFrame.  By [default](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format), `pickle.dump` uses an ASCII protocol, which is the least efficient protocol in terms of file size. This is done to ensure compatibility, and make it easier to recover as the ASCII protocol is human readable.

The equivalent for your code would be altering the `pickle.dump` line to:

```
pickle.dump(df, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I'd just use the `to_pickle` method, as it results in cleaner code.  There shouldn't be any backwards compatibility issues, unless you need compatibility with a very old version of Python; the more efficient `pickle` protocols were introduced in Python 2.3.

Another thing to note is that pandas uses [`cPickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) for improved performance, and not `pickle` itself.  This shouldn't impact the file size, but it's another potential difference between the two.  In general, you should use `cPickle` whenever possible, and only use `pickle` when what you want to do isn't supported by `cPickle`.

Comment: +1 That was it! I inadvertently used protocol 0 (ASCII), when I should've been using protocol 2 (binary format with efficient pickling of new-style classes). I tried pickling again with protocol 2 and I get the same exact size as the pandas version.

Btw, It's interesting to see that the `to_pickle()` method in `pd.DataFrame` is just a wrapper for `cPickle`. I don't know why I imagined `pandas` to have its own serialization scheme - but I'm glad to see it using base cPickle.

I also noticed the massive increase in performance between `cPickle` and `pickle`. I guess I'll use this from now on.